# How to get longitude and latitude using signalR in Rest Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub

I want to get the longitude and latitude of the device using signal R in rest service. I passed UUID (Unique Device id) and on the behalf of this id the application send me the longitude and latitude that where I am right now. Please help me out.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to create a ASP.NET MVC page, and return a visitor's latitude and longitude after they load your ASP.NET MVC page via SignalR? Or is the SignalR client a mobile app?

Comment: Rob Reagan I want to create a web api.The api returns the longitude and latitude of a visitor  in signalR client mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

If your client is a mobile app and all you need to do is report back a location occasionally to your server, SignalR is a lot of added complexity. You're much better off just having your mobile app call a ASP.NET WebAPI web service endpoint without dealing with SignalR.

SignalR is really useful if you need to call methods on the client from your server. If you just need to call methods on your server from the client, use RESTful web services instead.

That being said, if you do need to use SignalR to call from your mobile app to your server, you'll first need to do the following:

1. Install SignalR via NuGet
2. Configure SignalR in your app's startup

These steps are both discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).

Next, you'll need to define your Hub class along with the methods that the client can call. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubmethods).

And finally, you'll need to set up SignalR on the mobile app. I'm assuming you're using Xamarin so that you have a .NET client. The docs for doing so are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client).